# Efficient String Replacement in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

Is there any way to make this chunk of code more efficient? I'm not looking for someone to write my code for me, just to point me in the right direction...

```
    $string = preg_replace('/<ref[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/ref[^>]*>/', '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/{{(.*?)\}}/s', '', $string); 
    $string = preg_replace('/File:(.*?)\\n/s', '', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/==(.*?)\=\\n/s', '', $string);        
    $string = str_replace('|', '/', $string);
    $string = str_replace('[[', '', $string);
    $string = str_replace(']]', '', $string);
    $string = strip_tags($string);
```

The catch, however, is that the replacement has to happen in this order...

Sample input text:

```
    ===API sharing and reuse via virtual machine===
{{Expand section|date=December 2013}}

Some languages like those running in a [[virtual machine]] (e.g. [[List of CLI languages|.NET CLI compliant languages]] in the [[Common Language Runtime]] (CLR), and [[List of JVM languages|JVM compliant languages]] in the [[Java Virtual Machine]]) can share an API.  In this case, a virtual machine enables [[language interoperability]], by abstracting a programming language using an intermediate [[bytecode]] and its [[language binding]]s.==Web APIs==
{{Main|Web API}}
When used in the context of [[web development]], an API is typically defined as a set of [[Hypertext Transfer Protocol]] (HTTP) request messages, along with a definition of the structure of response messages, which is usually in an Extensible Markup Language ([[XML]]) or JavaScript Object Notation ([[JSON]]) format. While "web API" historically has been virtually synonymous for [[web service]], the recent trend (so-called [[Web 2.0]]) has been moving away from Simple Object Access Protocol ([[SOAP]]) based web services and [[service-oriented architecture]] (SOA) towards more direct [[representational state transfer]] (REST) style [[web resource]]s and [[resource-oriented architecture]] (ROA).<ref>
{{cite web
 |first       = Djamal
 |last        = Benslimane
 |coauthors   = Schahram Dustdar, and Amit Sheth
 |title       = Services Mashups: The New Generation of Web Applications
 |url         = http://dsonline.computer.org/portal/site/dsonline/menuitem.9ed3d9924aeb0dcd82ccc6716bbe36ec/index.jsp?&pName=dso_level1&path=dsonline/2008/09&file=w5gei.xml&xsl=article.xsl
 |work        = IEEE Internet Computing, vol. 12, no. 5
 |publisher   = Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers
 |pages       = 13â€“15
 |year        = 2008
}}
</ref> Part of this trend is related to the [[Semantic Web]] movement toward [[Resource Description Framework]] (RDF), a concept to promote web-based [[ontology engineering]] technologies. Web APIs allow the combination of multiple APIs into new applications known as [[mashup (web application hybrid)|mashup]]s.<ref>
{{citation
 |first       = James
 |last        = Niccolai
 |title       = So What Is an Enterprise Mashup, Anyway?
 |url         = http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/145039/so_what_is_an_enterprise_mashup_anyway.html
 |work        = [[PC World (magazine)|PC World]]
 |date        = 2008-04-23
}}</ref>
```

Sample output (with current script):

```
Some languages like those running in a virtual machine (e.g. List of CLI languages/.NET CLI compliant languages in the Common Language Runtime (CLR), and List of JVM languages/JVM compliant languages in the Java Virtual Machine) can share an API.  In this case, a virtual machine enables language interoperability, by abstracting a programming language using an intermediate bytecode and its language bindings.
When used in the context of web development, an API is typically defined as a set of Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) request messages, along with a definition of the structure of response messages, which is usually in an Extensible Markup Language (XML) or JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format. While "web API" historically has been virtually synonymous for web service, the recent trend (so-called Web 2.0) has been moving away from Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) based web services and service-oriented architecture (SOA) towards more direct representational state transfer (REST) style web resources and resource-oriented architecture (ROA). Part of this trend is related to the Semantic Web movement toward Resource Description Framework (RDF), a concept to promote web-based ontology engineering technologies. Web APIs allow the combination of multiple APIs into new applications known as mashup (web application hybrid)/mashups.
```

Comment: Maybe a sample of the input data and a sample of the output would be helpful, so we may suggest a completey different approach...?!

Comment: You can write all those pattern to an array and have a single preg_replace call to simplify the code. Same with str_replace.  Other than that, what specific concerns do you have with making it more "efficient".  What makes you think this is not most "efficient" solution? Have you done any benchmarking?

Comment: @MikeBrant: Have not done any benchmarking... Any suggestions on a good tool to do so?

Comment: Have you considering putting your string into a temporary read-write stream (like php://memory) you you can do some initial parsing in a file-like manner? You might be best served to use some parsing methods to do some of the work for you (for example `fgetss()` could parse out the <ref> tags straight of the bat when reading in the stream). You could also iterate through ignoring all lines that begin with `{{` (as these seem to all be at the start of the lines). You could get down to a bare minimum set of replacements that actually need to be done via regex or string replacement.

Comment: @MikeBrant: As a matter of fact, I didn't know that was possible. I'll definitely look into it!

Comment: Have you considered using the parser that this markup language uses (looks like MediaWiki markup?) and either strip out tokens out of the parsed stream if that's possible or simply parse it to HTML and then strip all tags? Markup to tokens which can be manipulated or markup to HTML to plaintext sounds much preferable to random Regex replacements.

Comment: @deceze: Yeah, I thought about making a parse call to the mediawiki api, but thought it best to keep as much work away from their servers as possible...

Comment: MediaWiki is open source software you can install in your own server too.

Comment: @deceze: True, I could, I just would rather have a solution that doesn't rely on any third-part (albeit open source) code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only removing things from your string (i.e. you have always the same replacement pattern), you can put all in a single preg_replace. In this way you will parse the string only once.

You can optimise your subpatterns by avoiding lazy quantifiers and removing capturing groups that are useless.

example:

```
$str = preg_replace('~{{(?>[^}]++|}(?!}))*+}}|\||\[\[|]]~', '', $str);
```

will replace your second line and the three str_replace

details:

```
~            # pattern delimiter
{{           # literal: {{
(?>          # open an atomic group (no backtracking inside, make the pattern fail faster)
    [^}]++   # all characters except } one or more times (possessive: same thing than atomic grouping)
  |          # OR
    }(?!})   # a } not followed by }
)*+          # repeat the atomic group zero or more time (possessive)
}}           # literal: }}
|            # OR
\|           # literal: |
|            # OR
\[\[         # literal: [[
|            # OR
]]           # literal: ]]
~            # pattern delimiter
```

You only need now to add the subpattern 1,3,4 to this pattern in the same way. Note that you don't need the s modifier since it never use the dot.

About strip_tags:

You can try to use a subpattern too:

```
$str = preg_replace('~<[^>]++>~', '', $str);
```

But be careful with that because your code can contains several traps, example:

```
blah blah blah <!--  blah > --> blah blah
or
<div theuglyattribute=">">
```

It is possible to avoid all these problems but your pattern will become very long.

Comment: If the replacements absolutely must happen in that order then I don't think merging all replaces into one would work correctly.

Comment: @tenub I don't think that it should be a problem, from the patterns the OP is using. There could maybe be at most 2 separate replace, a second for the replace of `|` to `/`.

Comment: @tenub: I don't think it is a problem, but if you are afraid with that, you can do it with the same order.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Any pointers on where I can find (or what I should google) to find a detailed explanation of the expression you used?

Comment: @AndrewBreksa: I will write the details.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Thanks, that worked great! I do need to replace the '|' with '/' though, so would I use the expression: `'~{{(?>[^}]++|}(?!}))*+}}|\[\[|]]~'` , and create a separate replace for the `'|'`?

Comment: @AndrewBreksa You could even merge them to [this](http://regex101.com/r/sU8qG8) and add a second replace for the `|`.

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks for that as well! I'll spend some time trying to break that one apart, good practice for me! :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Definitely learned something new today.

Comment: @AndrewBreksa: An other way to manage different replacement string is to use the preg_replace_callback function with capturing groups (for special cases), see the php doc.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Wow, the preg_replace_callback function is powerful. Allows for easy code updating later too, as I could define an array of strings and their replacements...